# How can i maintain the database for CMS in Bitbucket for a Drupal used website

Tags: 7, database

I am using Drupal 7 for my website development and my question is  How can i maintain a database for a version control system (Bitbucket). is there any best tools/ modules available to do?

Answer (score 0):

No. many have tried to version control databases and it simply does not work well.

If you want to manage config, you can use Features, which can save config and variables to code.